# Ejected Create-React-App unable to transpile node_modules code from Atlaskit packages

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, node-modules, create-react-app, atlaskit

Atlaskit packages in `node_modules` are causing Jest to fail in ejected create-react-app. I only have the default `App.test.js` file so far and receive a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` from `@atlaskit/dropdown-menu`.

[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnKZS.png)

I have looked all over the different questions on StackOverflow and Github Issues, and while the standard answer everyone keeps suggesting to try is to focus on `transformIgnorePatterns` in the Jest config, nothing I've tried seems to do the trick, so it may be a separate issue.

In `package.json` my current Jest configuration is as follows. It's the default configuration that shows up after ejecting:

**package.json**

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  }
```

I have also removed the `babel` configurations and `eslint` out of `package.json` and into their own separate files.

**.babelrc.js**

```js
const plugins = [
  [
    "module-resolver",
    {
      root: [
        "."
      ],
      alias: {
        atoms: "./src/components/atoms",
        molecules: "./src/components/molecules",
        organisms: "./src/components/organisms",
        pages: "./src/components/pages"
      }
    }
  ]
]

module.exports = {
  env: {
    development: {
      presets: ["react-app"],
      plugins,
    },
    local: {
      presets: ["react-app"],
      plugins,
    },
    qa: {
      presets: ["react-app"],
      plugins,
    },
    stage: {
      presets: ["react-app"],
      plugins,
    },
    production: {
      presets: ["react-app"],
      plugins,
    },
    test: {
      presets: [
        ["react-app",
          { 'preset-env': {
            'modules': 'commonjs'
          }}
        ]
      ],
      plugins,
    }
  }
}
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
    "extends": ["standard", "standard-react"],
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "plugins": [
        "standard",
        "react"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true,
            "javascript": true,
            "modules": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {

    }
}
```

I expect, that when `npm run test` is called, that **all** `node_modules` and not just `@atlaskit` related ones will be properly transformed into code that doesn't cause Jest failures.